# Unable to call the scale() method in Libgdx for android

Tags: android, libgdx

I've just started learning Libgdx from today by looking at some of the tutorials and find this framework really good, however, I've bumped in a minor problem. I've set up the fonts with the BitmapFont and was trying to use a method to scale the size of the text, however, I cannot find the scale() method. Did I forget to import something ? or pehaps miss something ?

I've imported `import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;` for the `private BitmapFont font;` I was able to change the color fo the font by using  `font.setColor(Color.GREEN);` But I'm unable to call some methods to scale the text .  Should I import the entire thing ? or should I have added additional libs  in the first place ?  I've listed all the imports that I have in my activity.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use scale. Scaling fonts looks terrible and should be avoided. Instead, use LibGDX's FreeTypeFontGenerator to generate the BitmapFont at the correct size for your application without any scaling.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype